# I am unable to install php5-apc on my Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, php5, php-fpm, alternative-php-cache

I am unable to install php5-apc.

I don't seem to get any errors.

```
root@applications-server-1:~# aptitude install php5-apc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
 php5-apc{b} 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 57 not upgraded.
Need to get 64.6 kB of archives. After unpacking 168 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-apc : Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.22-1~dotdeb.0) but 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.1 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

 Keep the following packages at their current version:
 1)     php5-apc [Not Installed]                           



 Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
 No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
 0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 57 not upgraded.
 Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.

 root@applications-server-1:~# aptitude install php5-common
 No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
 0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 57 not upgraded.
 Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

Here is information about my OS:

- Distributor ID:  Ubuntu
- Description: Ubuntu 12.10
- Release: 12.10
- Codename:    quantal

I am using PHP-FPM (PHP Version 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.1).

So can I do to install PHP5-APC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the dotdeb.org repository from your apt sources. This repository was designed for Debian systems and is not intended for (and does not work with) Ubuntu.

Comment: I was able to install PHP with it. It's just PHP-APC that I can't install. Plus isn't Ubuntu bested on Debian?

Comment: You were lucky the first time, that is all. Your luck ran out.

Comment: @Jean-NicolasBoulayDesjardins then you were lucky.  Ubuntu includes much newer packages than Debian uses.  Also, it appears that you have Ubuntu's PHP5.4 installed rather than dotdeb's PHP 5.3